# Cannot catch Tcl exception

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl

`Tcl_AsyncDelete` is bugging me for a long time now. Since it does not create any problem until I delete a particular thread, I have decided to ignore it. I have tried the following,

```
try:
    top.destroy()
except:
    pass
```

here top is the main Tkinter window and right when I try to destroy it The error pops up. But the code above is not working, what can I do?

Comment: You might want to include the _exact_ text of the error message as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a small [mcve].

Comment: If I remember correctly, `Tcl_AsyncDelete` shouldn't normally appear. I guess that you used `tkinter` in another thread. That isn't really an error as much as `tcl` (the library that `tkinter` uses) panics and just dies. Don't use `tkinter` from a thread other than the one where you created the `tk.Tk()`.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is that the process just dies, there's an *extremely* good chance that the problem is you're misusing threads. In particular, Tkinter objects ***must not*** be accessed from any thread other than the thread that makes them. (They internally use a lot of thread-specific data to avoid having massive amounts of locking, but that imposes *strict* thread binding rules. This includes in the memory management engine, which is *very* busy behind the scenes and which you really can't trick into letting you do what you want.)

If you are feeling extremely brave, you can run full Tkinter GUIs in two separate threads at once, provided you do the whole lot, initial window creation, main loop and all. But you're well into “don't do this unless you're an expert” territory, and the experts will tend to tell you “don't do this”.

Comment: It's possible to get widgets run by one thread living inside widgets run by another on some platforms, but it's _extreme_ wizardry and hard to imagine many practical applications for these days. (It used to be used for doing Tk GUIs running inside web browsers…) Also, I've no idea if Tkinter exposes the obscure API bits needed to support it; I wouldn't blame them at all for leaving those out!